# Worse performance after Hyperparameter tuning

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, loss-function, hyperparameter-tuning, gridsearchcv

I first construct a base model (using default parameters) and obtain MAE.

```
# BASELINE MODEL
rfr_pipe.fit(train_x, train_y)
base_rfr_pred = rfr_pipe.predict(test_x)
base_rfr_mae = mean_absolute_error(test_y, base_rfr_pred)
```

MAE = 2.188

Then I perform GridSearchCV to get best parameters and get the average MAE.

```
# RFR GRIDSEARCHCV
rfr_param = {'rfr_model__n_estimators' : [10, 100, 500, 1000], 
         'rfr_model__max_depth' : [None, 5, 10, 15, 20],
         'rfr_model__min_samples_leaf' : [10, 100, 500, 1000],
         'rfr_model__max_features' : ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2']}
rfr_grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = rfr_pipe, param_grid = rfr_param, n_jobs = -1,
                    cv = 5, scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error')
rfr_grid.fit(train_x, train_y)

print('best parameters are:-', rfr_grid.best_params_)
print('best estimator is:- ', rfr_grid.best_estimator_)
print('best mae is:- ', -1 * rfr_grid.best_score_)
```

MAE = 2.697

Then I fit the "best parameters" obtained to get an optimized MAE, but the results are always worse than the base model MAE.

```
# OPTIMIZED RFR MODEL
opt_rfr = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 69, criterion = 'mae', max_depth = None,
                            max_features = 'auto', min_samples_leaf = 10, n_estimators = 100)
opt_rfr_pipe = Pipeline(steps = [('rfr_preproc', preproc), ('opt_rfr_model', opt_rfr)])
opt_rfr_pipe.fit(train_x, train_y)
opt_rfr_pred = opt_rfr_pipe.predict(test_x)
opt_rfr_mae = mean_absolute_error(test_y, opt_rfr_pred)
```

MAE = 2.496

Not just once but every time and in most of the models (linear regression, random forest regressor)! I guess there is something fundamentally wrong with my code or else this problem wouldn't arise every time. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: In this case, maybe the default parameters are the best. And your forgot to include rfr_model__min_samples_leaf default parameter which is 1. Try again including it and you may have the same and consistent answer your are looking for. You do not need to fit again the best parameters, they are already fitted. See best_estimator_ property. ANd also you do not show code for the base estimator, please show it so we can check also.

Comment: Including the default parameter values works for Random Forest regressor but not for Linear Regression and Decision Tree regressor. I still get worse performance in both the models. Also one clarification, what do you mean by "you do not need to fit again best parameters, they are already fitted". Also i've included the best_estimator_.

Comment: In last 4 lines: opt_rfr_pipe = ... and opt_rfr_pipe.fit...  could be replaced by opt_rfr_pipe = rfr_grid.best_estimator_ which is fitted and ready to use for prediction.

Comment: One possible cause is overfitting: when tuning between many combinations of parameters, it's possible that one combination happens to fit the data better by chance. This is more likely in case the dataset is small.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to get worse model after optimization?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/82028/is-it-possible-to-get-worse-model-after-optimization)

Comment: @Malo ok I got it. But it still doesn't rectify the problem.

Comment: @Erwan So you mean to say that the hyperparameter values that I have given should be varied until I get the best result? But that would take too much time. There are literally infinite combinations of parameter values that I can try!

Comment: @BenReiniger I saw this question before posting my own and no it doesn't answer my question. In fact it doesn't answer the OP's question clearly.

Comment: The OP of that question apparently disagrees with you, having accepted the answer _and_ given it a bounty.  @Malo's point appears in that answer, but even after you've fixed that in your case for RF, I think the second paragraph of that answer is likely the right answer to your question.

Comment: One other diagnostic though: are these MAEs "significantly" different?  What's the scale of your target?  What are the test fold stds in the parameter search?

Comment: @BenReiniger The second paragraph says that distribution of test and train differ and hence the performance worsens. But I am getting this problem on other datasets as well and for different models too. (In the above case I am getting better results after hyperparameter tuning only in the case of Random Forest regressor but not in the case of Linear Regression and Decision tree regressor).

Comment: @BenReiniger Regarding your second comment, yes in the case of Decision Tree Regressor, base MAE is around 2.188... and after GridSearchCV, MAE is 3.2... so yes they differ significantly. Also sorry to ask but what do you mean by "scale of the target" and "test folds stds in the parameter search"?

Comment: @spectre you misunderstood my point: in case this was due to overfitting (I'm not sure it is), you should reduce the number of combinations, not increase it. Apparently you try 240 combinations, it looks reasonable but it depends on your data, in particular how many instances you have.

Comment: @spectre, sorry to be unclear.  First, what's the distribution of `train_y`?  (If they're all measured in the thousands, then 2-3 average error is insignificant.)  Second, looking for variability of the scores themselves, you can use the cross-validation scores from the search to get an idea: in `pandas.DataFrame(rfr_grid.cv_results_)`, you can view the standard deviation of the scores across folds, for each hyperparameter combination.  (If those are large, then the test differences of 2-3 can be chalked up to randomness of the data split.)

Comment: I hadn't realized your problem persisted in other datasets; are any of them sharable?  How are you performing the train/test split?

Comment: @BenReiniger I am using famous Boston House Price dataset (which is built in sci kit learn). So train_y is the price variable, so yes it might be in thousands, but when i check the train_y variable, all of them are in double digits(not more than 75).

Comment: @BenReiniger If by standard deviation of the scores you mean the split0_test_score, split1_test_score etc etc then in all the 5 splits the score varies anywhere from -5 to -2. The mean_test_score again varies from -5 to -2 and the std_test_score varies from 0.2 to 0.4.

Comment: Also this is for everyone. I noticed something in my code. For my baseline model I am training the model on my train set "only once" and then predicting on test set. But for my GridsearchCV I am using cv = 5 which will give me MAE (averaged MAE?) based on 5 subsets of training data. Maybe that is why I am getting worse results?

Comment: For the `best_score_`, yes; on a small dataset like boston, taking just 4/5 of the data for training each time, you might expect slightly worse scores.  (You also generally expect _better_ scores by selection bias, but that appears to be offset here.)  For the two scores on the test set, a difference of ~0.3 is not _too_ large given standard deviations of 0.2-0.4 (despite that being on the smaller-data chunks) and target values in the two-digit ranges.  There may still also be an effect of different-distribution testing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the reason I was getting worse performance was because I was using cross validation during HP tuning but not when I built the base model. Hence the issue.

Another mistake was not scaling my data!

Typical noob mistakes!